# IE setTimeout() only working when breakpoint inside

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have the following code in one class that gets instantiated many times. Each instance of that class goes through this code:

```js
var that = this;
setTimeout(function () {
     that.loadMapConfig();
}, 100);
```

That function, loadMapConfig, sends an async ajax request. Without the timeout IE marked all other requests but first as pending and never got sent. With the timeout, they don't even appear in network tab... unless I put a breakpoing inside the timeout, then each class stops there and sends the request.

Why does that happen? What can I do to make all those calls work in the background in IE? All other browsers work as expected, with and without the setTimeout() and the breakpoint.

Comment: Could be that the timeout is too small and while one request is pending, another one gets sent and interrupts the first one and so on

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE]? Are you sending lots of requests at once, maybe?

Comment: I think I was sending too many requests at once before the timeout. But now it doesn't even enter the function inside the timeout